# We can't install the 64-bit version of office because we found the following 32-bit programs

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, microsoft-office, 32-bit, sharepoint

I have Office 2013 64-bit installed. Never installed any other office version. When I am trying to install Sharepoint Designer 64-bit, I am receiving the error on the title. Tried Sharepoint Designer 32-bit. It says the same for 64-bit office. What kind of 32-bit Office programs might I have?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely a plugin/addin. I would strongly recommend uninstalling Office 64-bit entirely and only use the 32-bit version of Office because this is a common problem.

Whenever I need to install Office, I only go for the 64-bit version when its on a server environment, never for clients. It brings more harm than good, as in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any Office 2010 products installed, then you'll run into an issue there.  You can uninstall Office 2010 but if you are like me there are some part of Office 2010 you want to keep that doesn't come with Office 2013 (like Microsoft Office Picture Manager).  If that's the case then Visio 2010 still installs if you don't need the cloud version of Visio.